# Defining data in assembly

Tags: assembly

I have a simple program which simple returns a value to the shell:

```
SECTION .data
    value EQU 10
SECTION .text
    global main

main:
    mov eax, value
    ret
```

This works fine (displays 10 when I run `echo $?`). But what I really want to do is replace the second line with:

```
value DD 10
```

which I assume should work, but doesnt? It's giving me nonsense as a return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you're using NASM. So, if you've declared `value` as `value DD 10` you should use:

```
mov eax,[value]
```

To get the value of `value` (i.e. 10). The instruction `mov eax,value` would give you the address of `value`.

The syntax differs a bit depending on which assembler you use. In MASM/TASM syntax `mov eax,value` and `mov eax,[value]` mean the same thing (they both get the value of `value`).

Comment: That's odd. Why do they mean the same thing?

Comment: Who knows. Maybe they thought it would be easier for programmers to not have to use brackets. Of course you still need them in many cases (e.g. `mov ebx,[esi]`).